# Using cordovaGeolocation plugin I am unable to get user lat long below api level 21 (5.0)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova, android-gps

I am using below code to get user Lat Long but it throws error msg below api level 21.

```
.controller('DcompCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $cordovaGeolocation, $timeout, ionicMaterialInk, ionicMaterialMotion) {
    // Set Header
   var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
  $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
    .then(function (position) {
      $scope.lat  = position.coords.latitude
      $scope.long = position.coords.longitude

    }, function(err) {
     alert("error no LatLong")
    })
```

...
Thanks

Comment: any errors while debug

Comment: No, error is just thrown via function(err) block i.e 'error no LatLong'

Comment: is it working on other devices?

Comment: Yes, it works above api 21